# How to add images to listview (Rss Feed)

Tags: android, listview, rss

hi Am new in android right now am developing an application to list some date from RSS FEED
parsing and all other works fine problem is that i want to add images to the list view items.
the content is taken from RSS FEED.But the Rss Feed does not contain any images.i need to add images to the list view.and also the image is same for  all list items..

Parsing is done using DefaultHandler...

***This is my list item page***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    // A reference to the local object
    private MainActivity local;

    /** 
     * This method creates main application view
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set view
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Set reference to this activity
        local = this;

        GetRSSDataTask task = new GetRSSDataTask();

        // Start download RSS task
        task.execute("http://manna.christianchannel.us/feed/");



        // Debug the thread name
        Log.d("Reader", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    private class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssItem> > {
        @Override
        protected List<RssItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // Debug the task thread name
            Log.d("Reader", Thread.currentThread().getName());

            try {
                // Create RSS reader
                RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(urls[0]);

                // Parse RSS, get items
                return rssReader.getItems();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Reader", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result) {

            // Get a ListView from main view
            ListView itcItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainView);

            // Create a list adapter
            ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(local,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
            // Set list adapter for the ListView
            itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Set list view item click listener
            itcItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListeners(result, local));
        }
    }
```

}

***this is my RssParseHandler page***

```
public class RssParseHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private List<RssItem> rssItems;

// Used to reference item while parsing
private RssItem currentItem;

// Parsing title indicator
private boolean parsingTitle;
// Parsing link indicator
private boolean parsingLink;
private boolean parsingDescription;

public RssParseHandler() {
    rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
}

public List<RssItem> getItems() {
    return rssItems;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if ("item".equals(qName)) {
        currentItem = new RssItem();
    } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
        parsingTitle = true;
    } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
        parsingLink = true;
    }else if ("description".equals(qName)) {

            parsingDescription =true;


    }

}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

    if ("item".equals(qName)) {
        rssItems.add(currentItem);
        currentItem = null;
    } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
        parsingTitle = false;
    } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
        parsingLink = false;
    } else if ("description".equals(qName)) {
        parsingDescription=false;

    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    if (parsingTitle) {
        if (currentItem != null)
            currentItem.setTitle(new String(ch, start, length));
    } else if (parsingLink) {
        if (currentItem != null) {
            currentItem.setLink(new String(ch, start, length));
            parsingLink = false;
        }
    } else if (parsingDescription) {
        if (currentItem !=null) {
            currentItem.setDescription(new String(ch, start, length));
            parsingDescription =false;
        }
    } 
}
```

}

**this is my rss item page**

```
public class RssItem {
// item title
    private String title;
    // item link
    private String link;
    private String description;
    private String icons;

    public String getIcons() {
        return icons;
    }

    public void setIcons(String icons) {
        this.icons = icons;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
```

}

Comment: If "the image is same for all list items", you can simply add it in your xml layout, which describes the content of each row. Then you would add a drawable to your res/drawable folder and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @Michael's comment.

You need to create your own layout for your `ListView` item, as to add the same image to all rows.

Here's an example of the XML and how the `Activity` is created:

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ListView row item (listview_item.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.listviewtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        String[] arr = new String[] { "Android 2.3", "Android 2.3.3",
            "Android 3.1", "Android 4.0.4", "Android 4.1.2",
            "Android 4.2.2", "Android 4.3" };

            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.listview_item, R.id.textView1, arr));
        }
}
```

The interesting part is where you add your `Adapter` to the `ListView`.
In this example I add my own XML layout file for a `ListView` item and then afterwards I specify what `TextView` that should be populated with my text from my array of strings.